# Replace product name by SKU in Woocommerce admin orders pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, sku

Again, and it will be my last question on this topic (I apologize if I asked too much questions), I would like to replace the Product name by the SKU only in Woocommerce --> Orders --> Order Details in the backend admin of WordPress.

[image: sku instead of product name]

I didn't find any understandable explanation about how to do this on forums (I have really no skills with php code). I just found that the filter hooks that may be should be used is 'woocommerce_order_items' and 'woocommerce_order_itemmeta' but frankly speaking I don't understand how to use them.

Is it possible to know the correct code to replace the Product name by the SKU only in Woocommerce --> Orders --> Order Details in the backend admin of WordPress? If it is possible to have also some reference to understand about these hooks, I will really appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the composite filter hook made from [`WC_Order_Item` `get_name()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html#_get_name) method like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_name', 'filter_order_item_get_name', 10, 2 );
function filter_order_item_get_name( $item_name, $order_item ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $order_item->is_type('line_item') ) {
        $product = $order_item->get_product();

        if( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) {
            $item_name = $sku;
        }
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: As usual, your answer is perfect. Thank you very much. I do not understand what is the difference between a filter hook and a composite filter hook. Guess I should read articles about it.

Comment: Last question: what about sku in shipping item? [sku in shipping item](https://siamstylez.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/screenshot-siamstylez.com-2019.04.30-15-00-24.png) Is it the code `add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_shipping_item_get_name', 'filter_order_shipping_item_get_name', 10, 2 );
function filter_order_shipping_item_get_name( $item_name, $order_item ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $order_item->is_type('line_item') ) {
        $product = $order_item->get_product();

        if( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) {
            $item_name = $sku;
        }
    }
    return $item_name;
}`

Comment: @AlexandreDeplancke Sorry I don't catch… If you have another question, ask a new question please.